# Report a case on Bugzilla through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bugzilla

We have to report case daily to Bugzilla (includes files, many fields).

I see Bugzilla plugin available for Jenkins.

Jenkins is inside our infrastructure, while Bugzilla is at client's end (cannot be modified).
We can modify Jenkins at it is under our administration.

Is it possible to automate the case reporting to Bugzilla through Jenkins without modifying Bugzilla configuration?

Comment: _Jenkins is in out infrastructure_.  I don't know what that means.  Maybe you meant _our infrastructure_?  Can you access your client's Bugzilla from whatever machine your Jenkins runs on?

Comment: Correction - Jenkins is inside our infrastructure which we can easily access, while bugzilla is at client's end which we cannot access.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask whether the client's Bugzilla is configured to accept tickets over email.  See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791494/how-can-i-create-a-ticket-from-an-email) for more details.

Another option would be to run something on the client side that can receive messages from you and then interact with Bugzilla.  Alternatively, it might poll something at your office to receive Bugzilla requests.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case write a Selenium program that takes data from Jenkins to BugZilla. Both are webapplications So this should be possible.

Your best bets are the bugzilla API, e-mail or plug-in.